# When I do Geospatial querying in MongoDB, how do I also return the distance from my desired point?

Tags: python, mongodb, geospatial, database

```
for post in db.datasets.find({"loc":{"$near":[50,50]}}).limit(10):
```

How do  I get the distance between the document and "50,50"?

Answer (score 1):

Using the "geoNear" command will return a "dis" value as part of the results. Multiplying this value by the Earth's radius in the unit of your choice will give you the distance between that result and your original location.

For example, where "places" is the name of the collection and the lat/lng for your original point is 50, 50.

```
db.command( { geoNear : "places" , near : [50,50] } );
```

Will return a result in the format:

```
[
    {
        "dis" : 0.3886630122897946,
        "obj" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("4d9123026ccc7e2cf22925c4"),
            "pos" : {
                "lon" : -10,
                "lat" : -20
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Multiplying each result's "dis" value by 6371 will give you the distance in km, while 3959 gives miles.

There's more details and examples in the [Mongo docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing#GeospatialIndexing-NewSphericalModel).